# Spotify : 403 - User not registered in the Developer Dashboard

Tags: react-native, spotify, http-status-code-403

I'm making a react-native app with the **Spotify API**, I'm using the **Authorization Code Flow** & and I'm on **Development mode** with only one user added in **"Users and access" on my Spotify dashboard**: my tester, who is a part of my Spotify **Premium Duo**.

The app is working fine on my part, but my tester can't see anything related to her account. The **/me** endpoint is sending a **403 error** with this message in the body : **User not registered in the Developer Dashboard**. *Top Tracks / Top Artists endpoints are working fine with her Access Token*.

I can't see any email on her Spotify account, but can't change anything because it is linked to her *Facebook account*. I'm also logged in with my Facebook but it's working fine, and **I can see my details when fetching the /me endpoint** with my access token.

If you ever stumbled upon this kind of error, any help will be appreciated !
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can see your info using the /me endpoint because you're the owner of the app and automatically registered in the project's dashboard.

In order to use the /me endpoint on other Spotify accounts you have to register them in the dashboard of your project under "Users and access" in the top right corner.
Once the user is registered, the /me should return a 200 response containing all the user's info.

This is due to the fact that you're app is in development mode. Once your app is ready for production you can raise request for [extended quota mode](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/quota-modes)

The mail to use if the user is logged on Spotify via Facebook, is the Facebook one I'd say.

NOTE: You have to provide the user's real name to grant access: it's case sensitive.

Comment: Also found some additional endpoint to fetch regular user details. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-users-profile

This may not fit for the actual use case but worked for me with a bunch of additional validations.